# How to customize page size to A4 and line gap on exporting HTML page to doc/docx file in javaScript

Tags: javascript, export, doc

I have js function which exporting HTML page to doc file. The function works great, but in the exported doc file extra line gap is occurring as compare to the original html page and it's not A4 size page. I need to make the doc file page size A4 and remove the extra line gap. Can somebody help me?

I have researched about exporting HTML to doc/docx and tried some js code it is converting well but css page size code is not working.

```
//Here is my html code:
 <div id="doc_block">
// in this div content appends 
   <div id="view_delivered_articles_modal_quill_editor" class="WordSection1" style="display: none;"></div>
 </div>
```

// here is the js code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download_link_quill_editor', function(){      
        Export2Doc();
 });



function Export2Doc(filename = ''){ 
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft- 
               com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft- 
               com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC- 
               html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML 
               To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";


    if (!window.Blob) {
       alert('Your legacy browser does not support this action.');
       return;
     }

    var html, link, blob, url, css;

           // EU A4 use: size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;
           // US Letter use: size:11.0in 8.5in;

    css = (
            '<style>' +
            '@page WordSection1{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page- 
             orientation: portrait;}' +
            'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}' +
            '</style>'
           );

     html = preHtml + window.doc_block.innerHTML + postHtml;
     blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
          type: 'application/msword'
     });

      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link = document.createElement('A');
      link.href = url;
    // Set default file name. 
    // Word will append file extension - do not add an extension here.
      link.download = 'Document';   
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) 
         navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, 'Document.doc'); // IE10-11
      else link.click();  // other browsers
           document.body.removeChild(link);

   }
```

// I expect the export doc file size should be A4 and extra line gap to be removed.

Comment: Sir did you find an answer for this problem that I face the same ?